# Annotating a method to turn on performance tracing

Tags: java

I have a Test class with a method called `public void httpcall()`, I need to get the execution time of this method. In order to do this, I have used `System.nanoTime()` before and after calling it. I get the execution time from that duration.

code snippet:

```
public class Test{

    public void httpcall(){
        try {

            HttpResponse rs = HttpClientUtil.get("http://192.169.1.2:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users/9223370580466120397/roster",RestOpenfire.ACCEPT, "8V9BUNA0f1gNQI3S");


        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Error : "+e);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test test=new Test();
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

            test.httpcall();

        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        long duration = (endTime-startTime);

        System.out.println("Execution Time : "+duration);

    }

}
```

I want to make an annotation like `@Time` that gives an execution time of the method, something like ..

```
@Time
public void httpcall(){
    try {
        HttpResponse rs = HttpClientUtil.get("http://192.169.1.2:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users/9223370580466120397/roster", 
                RestOpenfire.ACCEPT, "8V9BUNA0f1gNQI3S");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error : " + e);
    }
}
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Annotations don't **do** anything. They're just metadata. You would need a runtime framework that would take an object, inspect the annotations present on the methods of the objects, call the method and measure their time. There are such frameworks. Google for AOP.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. can i used same in Spring framework ? Spring AOP ?

Comment: Yes, Spring has AOP suport. I'm even pretty sure that there are already metrics libraries that plug into Spring and do what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use aspectj which can either change your source code as part of your build, change your .class files in a process called weaving or change it on runtime.

https://mathewjhall.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/tracing-java-method-execution-with-aspectj/

Thought, it can be an overkill.
Unless you have a huge system that will be hard to refactor, I recommend using template methods. That is,

```
abstract class Measurable
{
   protected void abstract doWork();

   public void execute(){
     stopWatch = StopWatch.start();
     doWork();
     stopWatch.stop();
     System.out.println(stopWatch.getTime());
   }
}

class MyHttpClient extends Measurable
{
    doWork(){
        HttpResponse rs = HttpClientUtil.get("http://192.169.1.2:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users/9223370580466120397/roster",RestOpenfire.ACCEPT, "8V9BUNA0f1gNQI3S");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyHttpClient test=new MyHttpClient();
    test.execute();
}
```

And all uses of MyHttpClient will call the **execute()** method.

Also note that I used StopWatch class, since it is more elegant and standard than using System.currentTimeMillis. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html